# Ex 7.d - Norm properties and inequalities, Elements of Real Analysis, Bartle

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I am having difficulty proving a part of this question about the inequality Geometric mean less than equal to Arithmetic mean. The part (c) of the problem is:

> Let $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{m}$ be $m=2^n$ positive real numbers. Show that
>
> $\displaystyle{(a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{m})^{\frac{1}{m}}\le\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+\ldots+a_{m}}{m}}$

I proved this part of the problem, by using mathematical induction. I verified $P(1)$, assumed that $P(n)$ is true and proved $P(n+1)$.

The part (d) of the problem asks to prove the inequality in the general case, when $m$ is not a power of 2.

> Show that the inequality between the geometric mean and the arithmetic mean holds even when $m$ is not a power of 2. (Hint: $2^{n-1}<m<2^{n}$, let $b_{j}=a_{j}$ and $b_{j}=\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+\ldots+a_{m}}{m}$ for $j=m+1,\ldots,2^{n}$. Now, apply part(c) to the numbers $b_{1},b_{2},\ldots,b_{2^{n}}$)

**Proof.**

Let $b_{1},b_{2},\ldots,b_{2^{n-1}},\ldots,b_{m},\ldots,b_{2^{n}}$ be $2^{n}$ positive real numbers, such that $2^{n-1}<m<2^{n}$ and define:

$\begin{align}
b_{i} &= a_{i}\space & \text{ for }i=1,2,3,\ldots,2^{n-1},\ldots,m\\
&=\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+\ldots+a_{m}}{m} &\text{ for } i=m+1,\ldots,2^{n}
\end{align}
$

From part (c), we know that

$(b_{1}b_{2}\ldots{b_{2^{n-1}}}\ldots{b_{m}}\ldots{b_{2^{n}}})^{\frac{1}{2^n}}\le\frac{b_{1}+b_{2}+\ldots+\ldots+b_{2^{n-1}}+\ldots+b_{m}+\ldots+b_{2^n}}{2^n}$

The right hand side of the inequality simplifies to,

$\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+\ldots+a_{2^{n-1}}+\ldots+a_{m}}{2^{n}}+\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+\ldots+a_{2^{n-1}}+\ldots+a_{m}}{m\cdot{2^n}}(2^n-m)$

$=\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+\ldots+a_{m}}{m}$

I am not able to simplify the left hand side of the inequality to

$(\prod_{i=1}^{m}a_{i})^{\frac{1}{m}}$

Could someone lead me to the solution.

Thanks in advance,

Quasar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left hand side of the expression is:
$$
\Big(\prod b_i\Big)^{2^{-n}} = \Big(\prod_{i=1}^m a_i\Big)^{2^{-n}}\Bigg(\prod_{i=m+1}^{2^n} \frac{a_1+\ldots+a_m}{m}\Bigg)^{2^{-n}}
$$

Which simplifies to:
$$
\Big(\prod_{i=1}^m a_i\Big)^{2^{-n}}\Bigg(\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_m}{m}\Bigg)^{(2^n-m)2^{-n}} = \Big(\prod_{i=1}^m a_i\Big)^{2^{-n}}\Bigg(\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_m}{m}\Bigg)^{1-m2^{-n}} 
$$
Thus, the final inequality is:
$$
\Big(\prod_{i=1}^m a_i\Big)^{2^{-n}}\Bigg(\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_m}{m}\Bigg)^{1-m2^{-n}}  \leq \Bigg(\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_m}{m}\Bigg)
$$
Divide both sides by $\Big(\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_m}{m}\Big)$, you get:$$
\Big(\prod_{i=1}^m a_i\Big)^{2^{-n}}\Bigg(\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_m}{m}\Bigg)^{-m2^{-n}}  \leq 1
$$
Take the arithmetic mean to the other side, reversing the exponent sign:
$$
\Big(\prod_{i=1}^m a_i\Big)^{2^{-n}}  \leq \Bigg(\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_m}{m}\Bigg)^{m2^{-n}}
$$
To finish, take the $m2^{-n}$ th root on both sides:
$$
\Big(\prod_{i=1}^m a_i\Big)^{\frac{1}{m}}  \leq \Bigg(\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_m}{m}\Bigg)
$$

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks so much. Had gotten stuck, silly of me! :)

Comment: @Quasar That is ok, with so many indices you are likely to lose track somewhere.